# Errors saving app settings in C#

Tags: c#, application-settings

I know this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't get the basics to run...
Regardless of the application purpose (which is obvious)

```
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // these are *internal* properties of the NET appilcation
        FileSystemWatcher.Properties.Settings.Default.MailServer = Convert.ToString(txtMailServer);
        FileSystemWatcher.Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPort = Convert.ToInt16(txtServerPort.Text);
        FileSystemWatcher.Properties.Settings.Default.Subject = Convert.ToString(txtSubject);
        FileSystemWatcher.Properties.Settings.Default.MessageFrom = Convert.ToString(txtMessageFrom);
        FileSystemWatcher.Properties.Settings.Default.MessageTo = Convert.ToString(txtMessageTo);
        FileSystemWatcher.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

First issue is that I get a bunch of these exceptions when I hit this code...

> Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll

No other runtime errors I can see...
The app.config appears to be structured correctly - using Project-Add New Item.. etc and inspecting the app.config contents.
But the SAVE function listed above - doesn't save any changes I may make.

thanks

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: How do you know app.config is throwing error?

Comment: It appears (after setting a breakpoint and steppig through), that each of these is...
xxxx.Properties.Settings.Default.MailServer = xxvaluexx

Comment: I commented out all the lines except the first and the 'save()...
Still get a bunch of the exceptions - maybe 20+
No pop-up errors or crash-stop, just exceptions in the debug output

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is `FileSystemWatcher`? Is it your class or `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my folly... BEFORE I even knew there *was* a FileSystemWatcher class - I had already named my project ... you guessed it.. FileSystemWatcher ! 
So the namespace assumed I was talking about the class - *not* the app framework !

No compile errors of course! 
THANKS to all the helpers! 
Forgive me - I'm learning!